# Compare two List<int> and save same values to new list

Tags: c#

I have two lists of integers, I want to compare them and save the same values in a new list.

So if I have:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>()
        {
            1,
            2,
            3
        };

List<int> list2 = new List<int>()
        {
            2,
            3,
            4
        };
```

I would want a new `List<int> List3` that would contain numbers `2` and `3`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Linq Intersect methods which gives the common part:

```
    List<int> a = new List<int>();
    List<int> b = new List<int>();
    var common = a.Intersect(b);
```